# Why does sbt give "object swing is not a member of package scala" for import scala.swing?

Tags: swing, scala, configuration, sbt

Sbt version: **0.13.8**

Scala version: **2.11.2**

When compiling my scala swing application with scalac, it simply compiles.
However, when compiling the same files with SBT, it provides the following error:

```
[error] my/file/path.scala:1: object swing is not a member of package scala
[error] import scala.swing._
```

I added the scala version to my build.sbt. I **even** configured scalaHome  (which I believe should never be in a build.sbt).

The lines in build.sbt:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.2"
scalaHome := Some(file("/my/scala/location/opt/scala-2.11.2/"))
```

The

```
/my/scala/location/opt/scala-2.11.2/lib
```

directory contains the sacla swing lib: **scala-swing_2.11-1.0.1.jar** , this is also why scalac simply compiles.

Some might say I should add swing to my libraryDependencies in the build.sbt, however it shouldn't, since it is part of the core library and scalaHome is configured.

How to get sbt to notice the swing core library in a natural manner?

Bonus question:
How to configure scalaHome outside of build.sbt (**without** hacking the sbt jar itself) or better, have it notice the SCALA_HOME environment variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of 2.11, the scala swing package is no longer listed among [scala's standard library api](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/#package) and in fact is described in its own [README](https://github.com/scala/scala-swing) as "mostly unsupported".

I think you should expect to have to include it as a dependency.

See also [What's wrong with my scala.swing?](https://github.com/scala/scala-swing)

Comment: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.scala-lang.modules|scala-swing_2.11|1.0.2|bundle

Comment: It mentions "Additional parts of the standard library are shipped as separate libraries. "  and then mentions scala.swing.
It is also included in my scala installation as I mentioned AND scalac has NO issues. Only sbt. Why doesn't sbt consider my SCALA_HOME?

Comment: Just to clarify. I understand where you are coming from. However, everything said and done: scala 2.11.2 comes **with** the scala.swing library (well supported or not). And even though it is there, sbt does not pick it up.

Comment: Not sure what more to say. It comes with scala.swing, as a standard library [module](http://docs.scala-lang.org/scala/2.11/). Modularization's purpose is to make the core standard library slimmer. sbt has decided, quite reasonably I think, that non-core modules are dependencies that must be declared. scalac perhaps puts everything in an overstuffed lib directory in its `CLASSPATH`, but it's clear the scala team means for noncore modules to be omittable from the Scala platform when unused.

Comment: In sum, I think this is not a bug but a choice. You may disagree with it. (I think it's quite reasonable myself.) But I doubt it will change, because it is consistent with a desire to slim down the must-be-present core Scala platform. Its only cost is that you must declare a dependency in sbt (or point to it as an unmanaged dependency).

Comment: @SteveWaldman I guess you're right. I also apparently missed the following: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Configuring-Scala.html#Using+Scala+from+a+local+directory . It is indeed a case of "it's not a bug, it's a feature"